# How to subset columns based on row values in R?

Tags: raster, r, sf

I have extracted ERA5 temperature data for specific points that contain the day of the year when the temperature exceeds 10 degrees celsius. And now I want to see how the temperature develops hereafter.
Data:

```
head(df)
field_1   doy ID         1        2        3        4       5  6          7         8       9 10        11 12        13      14 15      16       17
69785317  93  1  0.1712229 1.335247 2.225898 0.588482 5.12949  0 -0.6848916 -2.910789 6.29925  0 5.5136687  3 3.1712229 6.19856  4 7.56689  5.34123
69785318  93  2  0.1712229 1.335247 2.225898 0.588482 5.12949  0 -0.6848916 -2.910789 6.29925  0 5.5136687  3 3.1712229 6.19856  4 7.56689  5.34123
```

The column names are `field ID`, day of the year `doy`, `ID` and the rest are actually the day of the year `doy` too, but for ERA5 data (up until doy 365).

I would like to set every ERA5 column that is before the `doy` for every single row to `NA`, and keep the columns with temperatures measured after the (row) day of the year.
So something like:

```
field_1   doy ID   1    2    3    4    5    6 ...         94        95       96 
69785317  93  1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ... 10.6848916 12.910789 16.29925
69785318  93  2   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA ... 10.6848916 12.910789 16.29925
```

I tried to subset the data as followed:

`df = subset(df, colnames(df)[6:9] > df$doy)`
I also tried:
`df[outer(rownames(df$doy), colnames(df), "<")] <- NA`
Both did not work, the latter since it is not a matrix I think. How can I change this to end up like my example given as the second code?

Edit:
I tried to perform Elio's answer, but with the `bind_rows` command I do not get the `doy` columns prior to 93. `field_1` ids of 69792725 and 69787246 are for example from day 80 of the year.

```
    field_1       93 94 95        96       97 98 99 100
1  69785317 1.883452  0  0  0.6848916 21.06042  0  0   0
2  69785318 1.883452  0  0  0.6848916 21.06042  0  0   0
3  69787245 1.883452  0  0  0.6848916 21.06042  0  0   0
4  69787246 1.883452  0  0  0.6848916 21.06042  0  0   0
5  69790938       NA NA NA         NA       NA  0  0   0
6  69790939       NA NA NA         NA       NA NA  0   0
7  69792725 1.883452  0  0  0.6848916 21.06042  0  0   0
8  69792726 NA NA NA               NA       NA  0  0   0
9  69792727 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA  0   0
10 69792728 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA  0   0
11 69792729 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA NA  NA
12 69794537 NA NA NA               NA 21.06042  0  0   0
13 69794538 NA NA NA               NA       NA  0  0   0
14 69794539 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA NA  NA
15 69794540 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA NA  NA
16 69794541 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA NA  NA
17 69796333 NA NA NA               NA 21.06042  0  0   0
18 69796334 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA  0   0
19 69796335 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA  0   0
20 69796336 NA NA NA               NA       NA NA NA   0
```

Apparently, you would have to sort the `doy` in an ascending order, so the lowest value is first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses `lapply` to store slices of your `data.frame`, which then are bound together with `bind_rows`, which allows for different lengths; code should be easy adapt to your object. Although this question should be better posted at stackoverflow, since the geographic part of the proceeding happened before:

```r
library(dplyr)

# build a df to essay with
mx_rw = 3
df = matrix(c(runif(365*mx_rw, 10, 20) %/% 1) %/% 1, byrow = F, nrow = mx_rw)
df = as.data.frame(df)
names(df) = 1:365

# fill field1 and doy according to number of rows
df = cbind(field1 = 69785317:(69785317 + mx_rw - 1), doy = 93:(93 + mx_rw -1), df)

# sort ascending, so lowest value is first
df <- df[order(doy),]

# slice each row, and put each slice in a list
df_sub = lapply(1:nrow(df),
       function(x){
         df[x,c(1,2,df$doy[x]:365 + 2)] # + 2 because of the offset: doy_columns start at 3
       })

bind_rows(df_sub)[,1:10]
#     field1 doy 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100
# 1 69785317  93 16 12 15 10 10 10 18  11
# 2 69785318  94 NA 15 13 18 15 19 10  16
# 3 69785319  95 NA NA 10 12 18 16 19  11
```

Comment: Thanks @Elio. I seems to be working, however, when I bind the rows it starts at 93. But I do have a `doy` from 80. But I do not get NA from thereon. They are simply not in there after the bind_rows command. See edit in question. And you are right, my background just made me post it in the GIS forum due to the spatiotemporal structure of my question.

Comment: Apparently, I need to sort them ascending, so the first `doy` value is the lowest observed.